# Split UTF-8 encoded string got from unichr

Tags: python

I have a set of unicode numbers , I need to convert them to UTF-8 and print the result in to split them in to hex values.

eg: Unicode 0x80 should be converted to UTF-8 and printed as (0xc2,0x80)

I tried following

```
str(unichr(0x80).encode('utf-8')).split(r'\x')[0]
```

But it does get split in to ['c2','80']. But it gives me ['\xc2\x80'].

I need this for code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a list of the hexadecimal values of the characters in your UTF8-encoded string, use the following:

```
>>> [hex(ord(x)) for x in unichr(0x80).encode('utf-8')]
['0xc2', '0x80']
```

Answer (score 2):

You want like this? could be done with list comprehensions.

```
>>> ["%x"%ord(x) for x in unichr(0x80).encode('utf-8')]
['c2', '80']
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to split with `\x`, but `\x` doesn't exist in the string. `\xc2\x80` are just the escape codes (like `\n` for newline) on your screen, I think what you want is this:

```
print hex(ord(unichr(0x80).encode('utf-8')[0]))
```